# Flutter error The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("videoId")

Tags: flutter, youtube, playlist

I want to make an app that can show list of video from my Youtube playlist for my group project. the list of videos are appeared on the emulator, but when I click(play) the video I received this error.

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("videoId")
```

here is my code

```
class ListVideos extends StatelessWidget {
  List list;
  ListVideos({this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i){
        return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => VideoPlays(
                    url: "https://youtube.com/embed/${list[i]['contentDetail']['videoId']}",))),
                child: Container(
                  height: 210.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(list[i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url']), 
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),),
                ),
              ),
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                Text(list[i]['snippet']['title'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                 Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                 Divider()
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this

Comment: can you show when you are creating this object? `list[i]['contentDetail']` is `null`

Comment: sorry, I'm not understand what you mean. I'm just start learn programming because my project required me to build an app. I learn to do this from tutorial on youtube

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As the error directing itself that your key named `contentDetail` is getting a `null` value that is why you are not able to get the `videoId`. To solve this error make sure that you are getting proper value in your `contentDetail` key or you can apply logic to hide the `Container` if the `contentDetail` is `null`, like below

```
Visibility(
            visible: list[i]['contentDetail'] == null ? false : true,
              child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => VideoPlays(
                        url: "https://youtube.com/embed/${list[i]['contentDetail']['videoId']}",))),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 210.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(list[i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url']),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                Text(list[i]['snippet']['title'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                Divider()
              ],
            ),
          ))
```

Comment: if I do this, it will not show the list of youtube video

Comment: you need to check whether contentDetail  has value or not if it doesn't have value then it will throw an error while calling the function.

Comment: Please mark this as answered if it worked for you and upvote also.